# Selenium C#::The xpath expression cannot be evaluated when RequireWindowFocus is set as true

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am executing tests in IE 11 browser using selenium webdriver. My tests run fine when the RequireWindowFocus set as False but when I set the property as true my tests are failing with exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException

stating

> The xpath expression './/*[@id='Password']' cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement".

The same tests are running fine when RequireWindowFocus  in InternetExplorerOptions is set as false. Can anyone help me understand the problem.

Comment: Can you try locating the element by id directly instead of xpath?

Comment: Ya its working fine when I change it to id but I am using xpath in all my tests, so changing everything will be a tedious task. Do you know why this is happening for xpaths, is there any way to fix this.

Comment: What if, instead of `*`, you would put an actual tag name into the expression?

Comment: Still the same exception is being thrown....I also tried with absolute xpath but the result seems to be the same

Comment: Is it a public site and you can share a link? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it's not a public site, so you won't be able to access it